# How to combine create and update actions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I have this controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(invoice_params)
    @invoice.build_sender(current_user.profile.sender_fields) # <= !
    if @invoice.save
      flash[:success] = "Invoice created."
      redirect_to invoices_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @invoice.update_attributes(invoice_params)    
      @invoice.sender.update_attributes(current_user.profile.sender_fields) # <= !
      flash[:success] = "Invoice updated."     
      redirect_to invoices_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Basically, what it does it when an `invoice` gets created, it also creates an associated `sender` record containing essentially the invoice's letterhead data, such as company name, address, etc.

When an invoice gets updated, its associated sender record gets updated as well.

I just wonder if this can be combined inside the model using a filter or a function like `create_or_update()` or something similar?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of constraint:

> Create/update an associated object B on each create/update of Model A

Should be held by the Model A. If tomorrow you need another page to create instances of Model A, you will not have to do the same logic in the two controller's actions because Model A is responsible for the creation of associated instance(s) of Model B.

---

So, in your case, you can combine an `after_create` and an `after_save` in your Invoice model:

```
after_create :create_or_update_sender
after_update :create_or_update_sender

def create_or_update_sender
  local_sender = (self.sender || self.build_sender)
  local_sender.update_attributes(self.user.profile.sender_fields)
  local_sender.save!
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But strictly speaking the two are not combined in one function using the approach you're suggesting above.

Comment: I can make it into one but it'll be a little more confusing.

Comment: Combining both methods will make it less manageable and readable. What @MrYoshiji suggested is the current convention.

Comment: OK, I went with the first option you suggested. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for first_or_create.update

```
Comment.where(user_id: 6).first_or_create.update(content: 'lorem ipsum')
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, one way is to try using action params like this:

```
def create_or_update()
  if params[:action].eql?('create')
    #code for save action
  elsif params[:action].eql?('update')
    #code for update action
  end
end
```

Comment: That looks like a bad idea. It's the same as having two distinct actions, just more complicated and error prone.